# How to roll back Spring data jsp example in service class (How to manage Spring data jpa transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

How to roll back Spring data jsp example in service class (How to manage Spring data jpa transaction)

```
@RestController
public class OrderServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @RequestMapping("/order/{orderId}")
    public Order giveOrder(@PathVariable("orderId") Integer id) {
        return orderService.giveOrder(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/save_order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
        return orderService.saveOrder(order);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/customerOrders/{customerId}")
    public List<Order> giveCustomerOrders(@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customerId) {
        return List<Order> orderService.giveCustomerOrders(customerId);
    }
}
```

Domain class

```
package com.kk.spring.entity;

public class Order { 
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ordet_tab")
    public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String itemName;
    private String address;
    private String zipCode;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepositry extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepositry orderRepositry;

    @Override
    public Order giveOrder(Integer id) {
        return OrderConvert.orderEntityToDTO(orderRepositry.getOne(Long.parseLong(id.toString())));
    }

    @Override
    public String saveOrder(Order order) {
        OrderEntity orderEntity = orderRepositry.save(OrderConvert.orderDTOToEntity(order));
        Boolean flag = myFilter(OrderConvert.orderEntityToDTO(orderEntity));
        if (flag) {
            return "Order next time";
            // here I need rollback the save data 
        }
        return "Order success";
    }

    @Override
    public List<Order> giveCustomerOrders(Integer customerId) {
        return null;
    }

    private Boolean myFilter(Order order) {
        if (order.getItemName().equals("TV")) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to manage Spring data jpa transaction in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Use @Transactional in your service class.  Now the context of transaction will be on service class instead of repository.